# Magento2 setup not creating table

Tags: magento2, setup-script

I have used **setup** to create **table** but script is not creating the table. I have also removed the entry from `setup_module` table but still, it didn't work.

`InstallSchema.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Create table 'rentals'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('rentals'))
         ->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'phone',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Phone'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Email'
            )->addColumn(
            'address',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Address'
            )->addColumn(
            'sku',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Sku'
            )->addColumn(
            'qty',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_Integer,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Qty'
        )->setComment(
            'rentals'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->endSetup();

    }
}
```

Comment: file name will be `InstallSchema.php`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note::** Delete module entry from table`setup_module`

After testing the code i found out there were two error `TYPE_Integer` and `TYPE_INTEGER`

tested code and workeing

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
//use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();


        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('rentals'))
         ->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'phone',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Phone'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Email'
            )->addColumn(
            'address',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Address'
            )->addColumn(
            'sku',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Sku'
            )->addColumn(
            'qty',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Qty'
        )->setComment(
            'rentals'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);


        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` followed by `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, but no table was created. Do I have to do something else?

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo did you delete module entry from table?

Comment: Yes, I did but nothing happened yet

Comment: what is your file location?

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo update the working code and test too.

Comment: Not working out

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo did you delete the entry in table and  run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46004/discussion-between-abhishek-dhanraj-shahdeo-and-qaisar-satti).